# SP Services - Object doesn't support this method

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I am getting a "Object doesn't support this method" error on this function when the function is called

```
function LoadCat(cat) {

        if (cat != null) {
            var liHtml = "Category:  <select name=\"categoryselect\" id=\"categoryselect\">";
        var CAML = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Department" /><Value Type="Text">' + cat + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';
        alert(CAML);
        } else {
        alert(cat);
        var CAML = '';
        }




       $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: "http://sp-app",
        listName: "Categories",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: CAML,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                liHtml = liHtml + "<option value=''>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</option>";

            });
            liHtml = liHtml + "</select>";
            $("#cat").html(liHtml);
        }

    });
    }
```

The error is coming on the $().SPServices({ line

It happens when the cat is null or has a value.

Been scratching my head over this for a few hours!

SharePoint services IS loaded before the function is called!

It seems the error ONLY occurs when I call it on this function:

```
  $(".area").click(function () {


      $(".area").parent("li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");

      LoadCat();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function LoadCat(cat) {
if (cat != null) {
        var liHtml = "Category:  <select name=\"categoryselect\" id=\"categoryselect\">";
    var CAML = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Department" /><Value Type="Text">' + cat + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';
    alert(CAML);
    } else {
    alert(cat);
    var CAML = '';
    }

   $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: "http://sp-app",
    listName: "Categories",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: CAML,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
            liHtml = liHtml + "<option value=''>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</option>";

        });
        liHtml = liHtml + "</select>";
        $("#cat").html(liHtml);
    }

});}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var subject = "Hi Subject!";
    var message = "Hi Message!";
    LoadCat(subject);        
});
```

Take a look at javascript console in your browser, there you can find useful errors. jQuery and SPServices must be loaded. For your tests you can even use cdn links for jQuery and SPServices.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```